# Getting erroneous "The size of a template cannon exceed..." error when creating list template for very small lists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm using SharePoint Server 2010.  My goal is to move an entire subsite (called "Internal") from test to production.  But the size of my "Internal" subsite is 1,190 MB which is far too large, so my workaround is to recreate the pages in the new (destination) subsite and then to create templates from the smaller subfolders in smaller chunks to move them over and then put them all back together on the destination site.

But when trying to create a list template on the small files and folders (even folders less than 1MB) I keep getting the error:

> "This list is too large to save as a template.  The size of a template
>   cannot exceed 52428800 bytes."

I have done the following to troubleshoot:

- looked up the files in Storage Metrics to verify the file sizes are indeed well below the upper limit.
- reviewed the ULS log files searching on the correlation IDs to see that the error is indeed an exceeds file size limit error. And it matches in the logs.
- increased default SharePoint file size limit on all front end and application web servers to 500MB using:
  Stsadm -o setproperty –propertyname max-template-document-size –propertyvalue 525288000

I've noticed that this problem only seems to be happening in one of my subsites (which is a team site).  But I AM able to create templates from large folders (200 MB) on the root site (which is a publishing site).  This confuses me because I thought publishing sites did not allow template creation.  It makes me think there is something about this particular subsite that is preventing templates from being created???

Does anyone know why I would get this file exceeds size limit error when clearly the file is well below the upper size limit?

I've spent 2 full days troubleshooting this and am stumped.